# Cannot write to ULS Logs under SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have the following simple code:

```
SPDiagnosticsService diagnosticsService = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
SPDiagnosticsCategory cat = diagnosticsService.Areas["SharePoint Foundation"].Categories["Unknown"];

string format = "Test trace logging for category {0} in area {1}";
diagnosticsService.WriteTrace(1, cat, TraceSeverity.Medium, format, cat.Name, cat.Area.Name);
```

I only want to write to the SharePoint ULS Logs. But this does not work. What could be the reason?

**UPDATE:**

Oh sorry!! I get no entries in the ULS Logs. ULS Logs are generated, but mine are not written to the Logs. All categories in diagnostics logging configuration in the CA are set to Trace level Medium and Event Level Information. There is no exception thrown, too. The code runs fine when I run it via F5 and step through it.

**SOLUTION FOUND!**

The AppPool Account has to be in the local Performance Log Users group! I have blogged about it here, too: http://www.bog1.de/2015/03/es-ist-nicht-moglich-in-die-uls-logs-zu-schreiben-performance-log-users/

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? Please be more specific, "does not work" tells us practically nothing about the actual issue you're encountering.

Comment: Oh sorry!! I get no entries in the ULS Logs. ULS Logs are generated, but mine are not written to the Logs. All categories in diagnostics logging configuration in the CA are set to Trace level Medium and Event Level Information. There is no exception thrown, too. The code runs fine when i run it via F5 and step through it.

Comment: Are you running this as part of an actual farm solution or just as a little console app (or something like that)?

Comment: Its implemented on a blank custom application page on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the reason why it did not work on the vm but I decided to setup a fresh one and to test after each step if my solution works.

It seems to be a config issue.

With the new machine everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this on the target SharePoint server?

Are you running it under a suitable SharePoint admin account?

You could try a more comprehensive example - from a google, something like http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/

Lastly, if you are calling this code from within a SharePoint Sandbox Solution, it will not work, you need to write a proxy. http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2012/01/sandbox-solution-uls-logging.html

Comment: Its running on the target sharepoint server, i am on the server and the page is called through the admin account which is the farm admin, too. I have tried this example and some other more complex examples from the net but without success. Even these did not work. Therefore i decided to test with a much simpler code. And last its not a sandboxed solution.

Comment: There are a couple more suggestions in here to help <http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/uls-is-not-logging-from-web-app> and the official guidance <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770300.aspx> Maybe go through step by step again and check each step meticulously, maybe you have overlooked something. Another option would be to spin up a quick VM with SP2010 and try on a clean environment.

Comment: Ok, i tried on another VM (which i set up 2-3 years ago) and here it works. But this is normally not possible!? The VM where it does not work is a fresh one with SP2. But here are running nearly the same apps from the other vm fine. Where could i look for.

Comment: Sorry @BOG, I cant debug your environment from here, but obviously there is something awry, I would start with checking that ULS logging is running, checking the event log, checking the ULS, checking your SharePoint versions, basically comparing the environments and ensuring your config on your new machine is good. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my solution was to change the monitoring level from inside SharePoint Central Administration.

Central Admin -> Configure diagnostic logging -> then select what you want log.